# backticks in variable name

Tags: r, syntax

If I create a variable with a backtick in the name, is there a way to access it using the backtick syntax?

```
assign("a`b", 5)
get("a`b")
#[1] 5

# The attempts below all end in various errors
# `a`b`
# `a``b`
# `a\\`b`
```

Comment: why specifically are you trying to access it using backticks?  Whats wrong with quotes, and are you sure there is not another way to go about this?

Comment: I think the answers can be summarized in one word - convenience

Comment: However you are running into such names, you can assign it to a variable, and then `get(.)` that variable

Comment: thanks, as illustrated in OP I'm aware of that option

Comment: I'm more curious why you'd encounter names with back ticks in them. I'm not complaining if this is just out of curiosity, but I'm not really seeing how this would come up in a practical sense.

Comment: @joran the issue came up as I was debugging some `data.table` code, and so one of the use cases that comes immediately to mind is column names in a `data.table`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All your attempts end in various errors because [`?Quotes`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) says that you can only escape the characters listed in the (included) table; and `` "`" `` is not in that table.

You could use the hex, octal, etc. representation of `` "`" `` though:

```
> `a\x60b`  # hex
[1] 5
> `a\140b`  # octal
[1] 5
```

Comment: But if you don't know *a priori* where the backticks in the column names are, what to do?  will running `gsub('`','\x60',colnames)` suffice?

Comment: The linked help version is for R-devel, and that actually does include backticks as an escapable character, so I guess that means a simple escape will start working for this soon.